# OpenMP Makefile, -fopenmp won't work

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to compile my project using a Makefile, but somehow the -fopenmp flag won't work.
Here's the Makefile:

```
TARGET=isaac
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -O2 -fopenmp
LDFLAGS=-lm -lpthread -lrt

OBJ=src/main.o src/bhtree.o src/body.o src/configreader.o src/diagnostics.o src/output.o src/quad.o src/timing.o src/vector2.o

isaac: $(OBJ)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: src/%.cpp
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean: 
rm src/*.o src/*~ isaac
```

and here is the output when calling "make"

```
g++    -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++    -c -o src/bhtree.o src/bhtree.cpp
g++    -c -o src/body.o src/body.cpp
g++    -c -o src/configreader.o src/configreader.cpp
g++    -c -o src/diagnostics.o src/diagnostics.cpp
g++    -c -o src/output.o src/output.cpp
g++    -c -o src/quad.o src/quad.cpp
g++    -c -o src/timing.o src/timing.cpp
g++    -c -o src/vector2.o src/vector2.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 -fopenmp -o isaac src/main.o src/bhtree.o src/body.o src/configreader.o src/diagnostics.o src/output.o src/quad.o src/timing.o src/vector2.o -lm -lpthread -lrt
```

the -fopenmp flag is missing when the source files are compiled, so the finished executable is serial, not parallel.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `g++ -Wall -O2 -fopenmp -o isaac`, it's right there

Comment: did mean `make -j4` to compile multiple files in the same time?

Comment: But it's missing for the compilation of the source files,
so all *.o files are serial, which means the flag has no use
when the linking is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your rule does not apply at all. You are free to remove

```
%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

and you'll get the same result as before. That's because some predefined rule is used instead of yours (I'm not great makefile expert though).

The core of the problem is that your rule is for `./*.o` files, but you need `./src/*.o` for `isaac`. You can change your rule

```
src/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Or (better) move all autogenerated staff somewhere from src.